# Instantiating object of generic subclass that inherits from non-generic base class

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance

I have a base class like so:

```
public class Base{
    private string name = string.Empty();

    public Base(string name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

and I have a generic class that inherits from the `Base` class and also contains a method that returns an object of the generic type `T` like so :

```
public SubClass<T>:Base{
    public SubClass(string name):base(name){}

    public T method(string parameter){
        //do some stuff here and return T
        return T;
    }
}
```

and I instantiate an object of the `SubClass`:

```
object instance = new SubClass<object>("name");
```

and I don't use the generic type in the constructor. the parameters in the `SubClass` constructor are predefined types (e.g string, int etc.). This implementation works fine BUT i'm wondering if this is this correct? is there another more appropriate way to do this. Thanx

**Edit**

The context:
The `Base` class is a class that handles the connection with CouchDB. so i provide the necessary info(username, pass, host, port and database name) and the `SubClass` is a simple client for CouchDB. So when I create an object of the `SubClass` I want to provide the credentials for the CouchDB and I want, also, to provide the model (e.g. Account model, Product model) that I expect from the database.

Comment: You've defined the subclass and it's constructor correctly. And you are specifying 'object' as the generic type when instantiating. But why are you storing the instance as an object? What's the point of creating a generic type if you then specify object? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit puzzled looking at your code. Why do you store your instance of `SubClass` in an object? That way you won't be able to invoke any members of your class (others than those inherited from `System.Object`).

> I want, also, to provide the model (e.g. Account model, Product model)
>   that I expect from the database

I'll assume these different types of models implement a common interface, so the structure looks something like this:

```
public interface IModel
{
    Foo GetFoo();
}

public class AccountModel : IModel
{
    public Foo GetFoo()
    {
        // whatever
    }
}

public class ProductModel : IModel
{
    public Foo GetFoo()
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Since we know that the type parameter of `SubClass` is an `IModel`, it would be a good idea to place a type constraint on `T`:

```
public class SubClass<T> : Base where T : IModel
{
    public SubClass(string name) : base(name){}

    public T Method(string parameter)
    {
        //do some stuff here and return T
        return T;
    }
}
```

And I'd use it like this:

```
SubClass<ProductModel> pm = new SubClass<ProductModel>("blurg");
IModel model = pm.Method();
Foo foo = model.GetFoo();
```

Comment: Thanx for your time here are some answers: "Why do you store your instance of SubClass in an object" : it's an example. Someone will call the library methods and it will return an instance of the class he will pass in e.g Account account = new SubClass<AccountModel>("blurg");"I'll assume these different types of models implement a common interface" : you can't assume, this will be out of the control of the library.

Comment: Even if you can't assume to have a design change as suggested, you should at least be sure that library methods return *type* of kind *class*. If that is true, then you need not worry, your current code is Okay and will work as shown here just with an exception that type parameter wont be constrained to model contract `IModel` as in this answer.